# Is there a better way to rewrite this function?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Is there a better way to rewrite the `foo[T]` function?

```
implicit def stringConverter(s: String) = new {
  def convert[T](): Option[T] = { //converts s: String to Option[T] }
}
def foo[T](m: Map[String,Buffer[String]], k: String): List[T] = 
  m.get(k).flatMap { x => x.map(_.convert[T]).filterNot(_ == None).map(_.get).toList }.getOrElse(List())
```

Comment: Actually explaining what you are trying to achieve might be of some help...

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion (if I've got your logic correct):

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

// Implementation.
trait StringConverter[T] {
  def convert(string: String): Option[T]
}

def foo[T](m: Map[String,Buffer[String]], k: String)
          (implicit converter: StringConverter[T]): List[T] = 
  for {
    lookupFromMap <- m.get(k).toList
    valueFromList <- lookupFromMap.toList
    convertedValueFromList <- converter.convert(valueFromList).toList
  } yield convertedValueFromList


// Instance.
implicit val intConverter: StringConverter[Int] = new StringConverter[Int] {
  def convert(string: String): Option[Int] = Some(string.length)
}

val map = Map("one" -> Buffer("1", "11"), "two" -> Buffer("2", "222222222"))

println(foo[Int](map, "one"))
println(foo[Int](map, "two"))
println(foo[Int](map, "three"))
```

I've separated it into two main parts, one being the base general implementation and the other being an instance of it being used. The convert method has been moved into a typeclass style of usage with a StringConverter trait, as the original convert method on its own doesn't really work.

Beyond that the main change is just to convert everything to a list in the for comprehension:

- Firstly we convert the Option from the .get call to a List.
- Then the Buffer is turned into a List.
- The the result of the conversion is turned into a List.